# I want to repartition so that I have more space

Tags: partitioning

As you can see, the bigger partition is for Windows. Turns out I didn't need it as much. And so, I'm thinking of enlarging the Ubuntu partition instead (to update to Ubuntu 14) but now, I can't since there are those two partitions in between.

Is there any way I can repartition this without having to format anything? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shrink sda4 (e.g. by 10GB) and then just move sda5 and sda6 to the left by the same amount. After that, you have space to enlarge sda7.
**But caution: Partitioning is always risky! Especially moving the left border of a partition, especially of a bootable system partition, can cause errors that might prevent your machine from booting! A backup is the best way to avoid data loss, so take the time and do it, it might save you much trouble!**

Answer (score 0):

How about just shrink `sda4` (I think windows can shrink itself, in case you're worried about windows' proprietary NTFS filesystem & linux's ntfs drivers) and then create a **new separate partition** in the new empty space,  for your `/home` folder, &/or for data?

A default Ubuntu installation only takes up under 8GB of space (I think, the installer won't run with less than that?), so after moving out some data &/or removing unneeded programs, should be a good amount of space left.

Comment: Mounting a separate partition as /home will cause the original home directory on the main partition to become invisible! You have to mount the partition first somewhere else, move the contents of the old /home over to the new partition (from within a live system of course!) and then edit fstab to mount the second partition now as new /home. Nothing I would advice a beginner to do...

Comment: Sounds about right. Not a beginner question, and I don't think guissmo said they were a beginner (just didn't want to format while repartitioning, which is a little like saying you don't want to turn right while driving...)